# UITableview inside a uiNavaigationcontroller inside a UITabView with XIB

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

Excuse the complete monotouch noob.

I have a main Tab controller that is the basis for the app, when I navigate to one of the tabs  I need is uinavigationcontroller with a uitableview inside it.

The main tabview I have handled.

the secondary view for the chosen tab, I went into IB and dragged a navigationcontroller over, 
I then dragged a uitableview ontop of that. So now I have the XIB set.

How do I declare this stuff in mono to hook it up ? The main controller is obvious, the class is right there, derive from UINvaigationController and it will load it from the XIB. Where do I declare the UITableView that is the sub view ? How do I hook it up to the XIB as its in the same XIB as the main navigation controller ?

Thanks for any pointers you can give, and apologies if this is a repeat question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to do so:

1. Make XIB-file with UITableView, but with no UINavigationController. If you want to see how a view could looks like, set view's "Top Bar" property values from "None" to "Navigation Bar". It's just for previews.
2. Add instance of UINavigationController to your AppDelegate;
3. Call UINavigationController.PushViewController with UITableView;
4. Add UINavigationController as view controller to one of your tab;

Example:
Imagine that UI of friendsView contains UITableView.

```cs
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // 1, 2
    Friends friendsView;
    UINavigationController friendsNav;

    ...

    // 3
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        friendsView = new Friends ();
        friendsNav = new UINavigationController();
        friendsNav.PushViewController(friendsView, false);

        ...

        // 4
    MyTabController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{
            journalNav, friendsNav
        };
    }
}
```

Thus, you will have 2 tabs journalNav, friendsNav. When you switched to friendsNav, friendsView with UITableView and navigation bar.